# Inline Ajax validation against a SOAP service on button click BEFORE clicking the form submit

Tags: ee2, ajax

I'm writing a custom module for EE which integrates with a SOAP service. I've built my own custom forms & actions and have no problem submitting the data via Ajax.

One of the forms is quite long and I now find myself in a situation where the client wants me to add a "Validate Address" button on the form, that the user would click to submit their address for validation (against the SOAP service), while they continue to fill out the rest of the form.

So the idea is that the "Validate Address" will submit only the address data to an action, which will call the service and then return a result letting the user know that they've entered a valid address or advising them to change something or whatever.

Once the user has filled out all the fields on the form they'll hit the submit button at the bottom and if the address has been validated, yay, the form submits.

My problem is that I can't put a form inside a form. So I figured I'd put the address related stuff in a div with a ID and the validate button click I'd submit the data.

The code looks something like this:

Comment: As written your question isn't clear. Please revise and add your code.